# ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier function unlockMessage(string name ) public payable returns (bool) { ^-----------^

Tags: solidity

I am trying to compile but i get this error message I can not figure out what is wrong with the unlock message

> ParserError: Expected '(' but got identifier
>   function unlockMessage(string name ) public payable returns (bool) {
>   ^-----------^

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract TrojanSecret {
// Data Types
uint memberCount;

string public name;
string public symbol;

mapping (string => address) Trojans;
mapping (string => string) secrets;
mapping (string => address[]) access;
mapping (string => uint) balance;
uint amount_for_unlock;

//constructor

constructor() public{
        name   = "Secrets"; 
        symbol = "S" ;
        amount_for_unlock = 1 ether;

}

function registerTrojan(string name) public returns(bool){
    if( Trojans[name] == address(0))  
    {
        memberCount ++;
        Trojans[name] = msg.sender;
        return True;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function unregisterTrojan(string name) public {
    require( Trojans[name] != address(0));
    Trojans[name] = address(0);
    memberCount --;
}
function setSecret(string name,string message) public {
   require (Trojans[name] != address(0)&& Trojans[name] == msg.sender);
   secrets[name] = message;
}
function getSecret(string name) public view returns(string){
    require( Trojans[name] != address(0));
    bool flag = false;

    for(uint i = 0; i < access[name].length;i++)
    {
        if(access[name][i] == msg.sender){
            flag = true;
            break;

    }
     if(flag){
         return secrets[name];
     }
     return "message is locked";
}

function unlockMessage(string name ) public payable returns (bool) {
        require( Trojans[name] != address(0));
        if( msg.value == amount_for_unlock){

            balance[Trojans[name]] += msg.value;
            Trojans[name].transfer(msg.value);
            access[name].push(msg.sender);

            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to format your code properly. See the "Code Layout" section of the documentation -> https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/style-guide.html#code-layout

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of the `if(access[name][i] == msg.sender){` clause. If you had bothered to maintain strict conventions of spacing, indentation and how braces appear in your code, then you could have probably avoided ending up with this kind of error.

Comment: Having done that you'll be able to see the missing closing brace in `getSecret()`.

Comment: I have made the updates suggested and i get this error now- TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type string memory.
balance[Trojans[name]] += msg.value;
^-----------^

Comment: function unlockMessage(string name ) public payable returns (bool){
    require( Trojans[name] != address(0));
    if( msg.value == amount_for_unlock){

        balance[Trojans[name]] += msg.value;
        Trojans[name].transfer(msg.value);
        access[name].push(msg.sender);

        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it's not a question, it's a code-dump, and similarly to [this "question"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/72538/16043), if this dude/lady had maintained his/her code properly organized, then he/she could have probably avoided dumping his/her syntax errors here.

Answer (score 1):

This { isn't closed.

```
if(access[name][i] == msg.sender){
```